# Get Transformation details using a table name in PDI Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I know my database table name and it is being used in one of the transformation in Pentaho PDI transformations which is inside a job. But I don't know where else the same table is used in other transformations of my repo.
Is there a way to find the list of transformations where all the same table is used by some search or meta data find?

Answer (score 0):

PDI transformations and jobs are xml files with a different extension, so any methods your OS allows to search for content inside text files will work, for example, `grep` in Linux.

Comment: In windows: 

https://anytxt.net/3-ways-to-search-content-of-files-windows-10/#:~:text=Findstr%20is%20a%20built%2Din,from%20an%20elevated%20command%20prompt.

Answer (score 0):

[Ana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77474003/6480762) before is the normal and correct answer.

However sometimes grep is not a real option, for example if you have a lot of tables with the same names in diffrent systems, or if you have the same table in diffrent schema (in case of for example in a multitenant postgreql databaseserver). A dirty but easy way to find out is then on a test environment, just alter one character in the table name and see which transformation throws an error.

On another note, if your code is so clouded that you can't retrace where a certain table is being used, then you might have some other issues in your design...